# how do i stop a hover function toggling when dragging and dropping an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-hover, jquery-ui-droppable

Hello guys I have a menu that expands when it is hovered over with the mouse, within the expanded menu I have elements which can be dragged and dropped. However, the second you attempt to drag an element, the hovered menu toggles back to it's unexpanded state even though you are still over it, can you help me?

JQuery for the expandable menu when hovered:

```
$( ".rightmenucont" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( "#rightmenu"  ).addClass( "expandedmenu" );
    }, function() {
        $( "#rightmenu"  ).removeClass( "expandedmenu" );
    }
);
```

Jquery for the dragged item:

```
$(".menuitem").draggable({ 
    cancel: ".stuck", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: function() { 
        return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show();
    }
})

$(".menubar").droppable({
    accept:".menuitem",
    drop: function (ex, ui){
        var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
    }
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated i just need the menu to stay open when dragging and dropping of the elements within the menu and then to close when the mouse stops hovering over the menu.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (prefered method as of jQuery v1.7)  or [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) at the point when you want to unbind the event handling:

```
$('.rightmenucont').off('hover');
```

or

```
$(".rightmenucont").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Than you bind it whenever you want to activate it, for which you could store your function:

```
var mouseEnterHandler = function() {
    $( "#rightmenu"  ).addClass( "expandedmenu" );
};
var mouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    $( "#rightmenu"  ).removeClass( "expandedmenu" );
};
```

and than bind it whenever you need it like this:

```
 $(".rightmenucont").hover(mouseEnterHandler, mouseLeaveHandler);
```

Comment: thanks but didn't realy achieve what i wanted in the way of i feel theres more lines of code needed than i need, so i did it like this but don't really like it ...
     $(".rightmenucont").hover(mouseEnterHandler);

     $("#centerpage").hover(mouseLeaveHandler);
     $("#mainmenu").hover(mouseLeaveHandler);

Comment: You're doing it wrong. When you give only one parameter to the method `.hover()` you are handling the mouse enter and mouse leave events on `mouseLeaveHandler` method.